# Django no guarda objetos despues de save() cuando comparo en el test pero si funciona por shell

Tags: django, test

Más que un problema es una duda de no saber qué esta pasando, la lógica no es muy compleja y el código al menos por shell me funciona bien pero cuando quiero escribir test para probarlo me da error y me gustaría saber por qué... la lógica es la siguiente: Tengo 3 modelos de perfiles (Administrator, Evaluated y Evaluator) y cada uno tiene un documento (Document) que tiene una pareja única de tipo y valor (digamos tipo = "DNI", valor = "777", solo como ejemplo) en caso exista un Administrator con un documento que tenga tipo y valor igual a lo que estoy enviando debe dar error porque no puede haber 2 cuentas Administrator con el mismo Document, pero si es un Evaluated o Evaluator no debe crear ningún Document sino solo agregarlo al Document del Administrator que ya existe, este es el modelo Document:

```
class Document(TimeStampedModel):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Tipo")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Valor")
    administrator = models.ForeignKey(
        "Administrator", related_name="documents", blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name="Administrador")
    evaluated = models.ForeignKey(
        "Evaluated", related_name="documents", blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name="Evaluado")
    evaluator = models.ForeignKey(
        "Evaluator", related_name="documents", blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name="Evaluador")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Documento"
        unique_together = ("type", "value")

    def __str__(self):
        for person in (self.administrator, self.evaluated, self.evaluator):
            if person:
                return person.user.get_full_name()

    def save(self):
        if not any([self.administrator, self.evaluated, self.evaluator]):
            raise ValidationError(
                "No se puede crear un documento sin una persona asociada")
        documents_qs = Document.objects.filter(
            type=self.type, value=self.value)
        if documents_qs.exists():
            if self.id:
                return super().save()
            else:
                document = documents_qs.first()
                if self.administrator:
                    if document.administrator:
                        raise ValidationError(
                            "Ya existe un administrador con este documento")
                    else:
                        document.administrator = self.administrator
                        document.save()
                if self.evaluated:
                    if document.evaluated:
                        raise ValidationError(
                            "Ya existe un evaluado con este documento")
                    else:
                        document.evaluated = self.evaluated
                        document.save()
                if self.evaluator:
                    if document.evaluator:
                        raise ValidationError(
                            "Ya existe un evaluador con este documento")
                    else:
                        document.evaluator = self.evaluator
                        document.save()
        else:
            return super().save()
```

y este es el test que me falla, cuando le pongo print al nuevo documento me sale id = None cuando me debería salir id = el id del documento que esta actualizando... en todo caso si el código funciona en shell y el test falla lo que esta mal es el test pero me gustaría saber por qué o como debería escribir los test, gracias de antemano

```
class DocumentTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.evaluator = mommy.make(Evaluator)
        self.document_evaluator = mommy.make(
            Document, evaluator=self.evaluator)

    def test_new_administrator_with_other_existing_document(self):
        document_type = self.document_evaluator.type
        document_value = self.document_evaluator.value
        administrator = mommy.make(Administrator)
        document_new = Document(
            type=document_type, value=document_value,
            administrator=administrator)

        document_new.save()
        self.document_evaluator.save()

        print(self.document_evaluator.__dict__)
        print(document_new.__dict__)
        print("----------")
        print(self.document_evaluator.pk)
        print(document_new.pk)
        print("----------")
        print(self.document_evaluator._state.adding)
        print(document_new._state.adding)

        self.assertEqual(
            self.document_evaluator.id, document_new.id)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.document_evaluator.delete()
        self.evaluator.delete()
```

PD: Puse los prints para ver lo que esta pasando, también en el objeto _state el adding me sale en uno True y en el otro False por más que estoy después del save() y no pongo los otros test para no hacer aún más extensa esta publicación (y también porque esos no dan error :D ), gracias de antemano

Comment: Asumo que el `TestCase` que estás usando es el propio de Django y no unittest, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si, del mismo Django